# Unable to Download Torrents After Windows 10 Install

Tags: windows-10, vpn, bittorrent, transmission

I'm just trying to download a small, simple magnet torrent to see that everything is functioning (the magnet torrent from ipleak.net). It just sits there at 0KB, 0%, 0 peers and never moves.

I have recently installed Windows 10 x64 Pro. I have tried qBitTorrent and Transmission clients, both with the same results. I have my VPN, Windows Firewall, and Windows Defender turned off.

Is there a registry setting or something that I can edit/add/remove? Or a known issue?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your inability to download torrents has to do with you not forwarding ports it does not have anything to do with Windows 10.

Comment: Oh, I'm using the same client, settings, and magnet links on my Windows 10 desktop and on my Windows 7 laptop.  The laptop has no problem handling it, that is why I assumed it was a Windows 10 issue.

What should I do to get the ports forwarding to resolve the issue on the Windows 10 PC?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few things you should check :

- Is the torrent seeded ? If it's not, you won't be able to download, since no one can provide the file
- Is it using UDP ? Some tracker are mainly UDP, which is often blocked by torrent clients

Comment: Kindly explain and provide a solution in your answer

Comment: Yea, it's seeded.  It's a magnet created by ipleak.net to test your IPv4 security.  I'm able to use the same client and magnet on my laptop with Windows 7 and it works great.